# Difference between tuples (all or none)

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have two sets as follows:

```
house_1 = {('Gale', '29'), ('Horowitz', '65'), ('Galey', '24')}
house_2 = {('Gale', '20'), ('Horowitz', '65'), ('Gale', '29')}
```

Each tuple in each set contains attributes that represent a person. I need to find a special case of the symmetric set difference between `house_1` and `house_2`: the difference must be confirmed only if all elements of the tuples disagree, and not any one of them.

For the above sets, `house_1 ^ house_2` yields:

```
{('Gale', '20'), ('Galey', '24')}
```

which is great. However, in the following sets:

```
house_1 = {('Gale', '24')}
house_2 = {('Gale', '29')}
```

doing `house_1 ^ house_2` still yields:

```
{('Gale', '24'), ('Gale', '29')}
```

This isn't what I want. I need the set difference to be output only when both elements in the tuples do not match. In this case Gale matches, so both these tuples should not be in the output.

Any insights are greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

I wrote the following function to solve this:

```
for counter_H1, member_H1 in enumerate(house_1):
    for counter_H2, member_H2 in enumerate(house_2):
        if (member_H1[0] == member_H2[0]) and (member_H1[1] == member_H2[1]):
            break

        if (member_H1[0] != member_H2[0]) and (member_H1[1] != member_H2[1]) and (counter_H2 == len(house_2) - 1):
            print(member_H1, member_H2)
```

Comment: Your operation is underspecified. You seem to be assuming some sort of implicit bijection where each element of one set is matched up with a specific element of the other set. Why is `('Gale', '20')` included in the symmetric difference when it could be matched with `('Gale', '29')` in the first set?

Comment: @user2357112 I don't follow your last sentence. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You should use comprehension. But I think that you should go with dicts, not sets.

Comment: @lostsoul29 I think user2357112's question  is why `('Gale', '20')` should be in the first difference. Given the logic you want, it seems like it should have matched with one of the other `'Gale'` tuples.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for clearing it up. There is an injection between the two sets. A tuple `x` from `house_1` matches to a tuple `y` from `house_2` iff all elements in `x` match with elements of `y`, in order. `('Gale', '20')` does not match with `('Gale', '29')` because the second elements do not match.

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand what you want at all. If both parts need to match, then why should`('Gale', '24')` and `('Gale', '29')` be considered a match in the second difference?

Comment: @Blckknght It shouldn't. I say that that is what the set symmetric difference function gives me, but I don't want that in the output since Gale matches. Please read the question carefully again.
My apologies if the question has not been explained clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could count the occurences of names in the result and print only tuples that correspond to the names with the count of 1:

```
from collections import defaultdict

count = defaultdict(list)

for x in house_1 ^ house_2:
    count[x[0]].append(x)
for v in count.values()
    if len(v) == 1:
        print(*v)
```

Comment: I found an issue with your answer. If I change the order of the elements of the tuples, it doesnt work. For example, if the sets are now `house_1 = {('24', 'Gale')}` and `house_2 = {('29', 'Gale')}`, the output is `('29', 'Gale')
('24', 'Gale')` even though Gale matches.